# How to set constant figsize in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I am doing some experimentations with plotting and I like big plots i.e plots on a big picture. So I have to manually do

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
myplotcode
```

every time.
I want to know is there anyway that I set this `figsize` as constant in starting and do not use it manaully everytime.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `MatplotLib` to can edit the base parameters, which is arranged in a dict form.
You can actually change every default parameter.
In your case it would like this:

```
rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [15, 8]
```

For more parameters you can change, you can check out the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html).

Comment: @ipj only until the process exits

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set the figure size once and forever you can store you preferences (not only the figure size) in an initialization file, named `matplotlibrc`

On linux/Unix like systems

```
$ mkdirhier ~/.config/matplotlib
$ echo "figure.figsize     : 10, 7" >> /home/boffi/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc
$ python
...
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot
>>> matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
<Figure size 1000x700 with 0 Axes> 
>>> # the above size is in pixels, at the default of 100 dpi
>>>
```

To know the location of the configuration directory you can do

```
$ python
...
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.get_configdir()
'/home/user1001/.config/matplotlib'
>>>
```

---

An initialization file is good for you, but if you want to distribute your script to other people, with different initialization files, well it's no more so good!

A possible remedy is to go with Matplotlib's [style sheets](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html)
that allows you to load all of your tweakings with a single statement

```
plt.style.use('./mystyle.mplstyle')
```

and also the possibility of using a style as a context manager

```
plt.plot(...)         # default style
with plt.style.context('./mystyle.mplstyle'):
     plt.plot(...)    # your style
```

so that you can distribute your style sheet along with your script and your user will not be affected by a global modification of the defaults.